# Fetching value from another Redux slice as initial state in a different slice

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-state-management

I have two Redux slices in my application: userSlice and cartSlice. I would like to fetch a specific value (**userName**) from the **userSlice** and assign it as the initial value for a property (**user**) in the **cartSlice**. However, I'm having trouble achieving this.

Here's the code for userSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const userNameLocalStorage =
    localStorage.getItem("userRedux") === null
        ? null
        : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userRedux"));

const initialState = {
    userName: userNameLocalStorage,
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateUser: (state, action) => {
            localStorage.setItem("userRedux", action.payload)
            state.userName = action.payload;
        },
        logOut: (state) => {
            window.localStorage.removeItem('userRedux');
            state.userName = null;
        },

    },
})

export const { updateUser,logOut } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

here is code for cartSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userSlice } from './userSlice';

const initialState = {
    numberOfItems: 0,
    details: [],
    total: 0,
    user: userSlice?.initialState?.userName,
}
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    },

})

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

both are in same directory

I tried importing the userSlice and accessing userSlice.initialState.userName as the initial value for the user property in cartSlice, but it didn't work as expected. The user property in cartSlice is always undefined.

How can I fetch the userName value from userSlice and assign it as the initial value for the user property in cartSlice? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

See [Return Value](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#return-value) of `createSlice()` function.

`createSlice` will return an object that looks like:

```js
{
    name : string,
    reducer : ReducerFunction,
    actions : Record<string, ActionCreator>,
    caseReducers: Record<string, CaseReducer>.
    getInitialState: () => State
}
```

So, try `userSlice.getInitialState().userName`

package versions:

```json
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
```